# Call a method until an element becomes visible - Katalon

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, katalon-studio

I am trying to call a method until a particular element becomes visible. The element in question is always present on the webpage but it only becomes visible if a particular button is clicked.

I am trying to do something like do…while in groovy

```
while (true){
            selectFirstAvailableOption();
            if (WebUI.verifyElementVisible(findTestObject('ProductDetailsPage/PickUpAtStoreOption'), FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

I want to continue calling `selectFirstAvailableOption()` until `ProductDetailsPage/PickUpAtStoreOption` becomes visible.

Currently my test goes in infinite loop and the test keeps on running. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It isn't obvious from looking at the code why the element never becomes visible or isn't detected as visible, but the way you have written that test isn't great because the test is trying to make sure the thing is visible but has no way to ever say that the element is not visible because the loop runs forever.  I don't know Katalon and don't know if it provides a mechanism to say something like "verify this element is visible, and give up after 500ms and fail the test" but if it doesn't, you probably should code that in your test instead of a potentially infinite `while(true)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to verify that element is visible, you want to wait for it to become visible. Try this

```
while (true){
            selectFirstAvailableOption();
            if (WebUI.waitForElementVisible(findTestObject('ProductDetailsPage/PickUpAtStoreOption'), 10)) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

More info on [documentation page](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-wait-for-element-visible.html#example).